# Gridview row id

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have `Gridview` full with data and I need when some of rows are checked i can be able to press the button and change the data accordingly, I can do it when all rows are checked but i can't find a way to connect my queries with id of one or many rows.

```
    protected void UsedForButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            var chk = row.FindControl("InStockCbx") as CheckBox;
            if (chk.Checked)
            {
                //using (WorkDBEntities db = new WorkDBEntities())
                //{

                //    WorkTable table = new WorkTable();
                //    table.InStock = 0;

                //    db.WorkTables.Add(table);
                //    db.SaveChanges();    
                //}
                string query = "UPDATE WorkTable SET InStock = 0 WHERE Id = " ???;

                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                conn.Open();
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
```

Comment: can you add ASPX part. So I can understand easily. Need more details

Answer (score 0):

@Nemanja, you want to get Id of each record then only you will be able to update based on Id. First bind Id of the record into grid and try to get id in button click event

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void UsedForButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox checkbox1 = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("InStockCbx");
        if (checkbox1.Checked)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString());           
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("UPDATE WorkTable SET InStock = 0 WHERE Id = @Id"", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: You need to specify Data Key in your `.aspx` template like here:*

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id" ...>
```